Cordova inAppBrowser cannot navigate once page is loaded
I'm running this code (same result with different URLs) on Android API 34 (emulator)
    var url = 'https://cordova.apache.org/';
    var target = "_blank";
    var options = "location=yes,hidden=yes,beforeload=yes";
    browser = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);
    browser.show();

The page loads fine but then links do not work from within the loaded page. Am I missing something? Or is the plugin broken ?
    cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 6.0.0
    cordova-android 13.0.0
          



    


Leaving for the next guy. The beforeload options seems broken.
This does not work
var options = "location=yes,hidden=yes,beforeload=yes";
This works
var options = "location=yes,hidden=yes,beforeload=no";
